# ios - Share video on Facebook using FBSDKShareDialog

Tags: ios, objective-c, fbsdk

I have an application that should share the last video from Camera Roll on facebook wall.

The code I am using is:

```
PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
            [fetchOptions setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:false], nil]];



        PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeVideo options:fetchOptions];

        NSString *videoIdentifier = @"";

        if(fetchResult != nil) {

            if ([fetchResult count] > 0) {
                if ([[fetchResult firstObject] isKindOfClass: [PHAsset class]]) {
                    videoIdentifier = [((PHAsset *)[fetchResult firstObject]) localIdentifier];

                    NSArray *array = [videoIdentifier componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

                    NSString *urlAssetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=%@&ext=MOV", array.firstObject];

                    FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
                    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAssetString];

                    FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
                    video.videoURL = videoURL;

                    FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
                    content.video = video;

                    shareDialog.shareContent = content;
                    shareDialog.delegate = self;
                    [shareDialog show];
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem are:

1) Instead of opening a share dialog inside the app, it opens the facebook app

2) When I confirm the share, a black screen appears with an spinner. When the spinner reach 100% progress it remains on the screen. None of the delegate methods are called.

3) The post isn't share at the end / doesn't appear on the wall

What should I do? Is it something wrong if I don't have a Facebook login in the application to give the permission to post on wall?

[image]
[image]

Comment: you cant use ios's nice built in socail stuff to share video, only picstures and text so as far as i know you have to use FBSDK which then opens the app or safari ... which i know sucks ass!

Comment: Ok, but what's with the spinner that remains stuck there and also the post it's not shared?